# sitecore email campaigns manager newsletter issue

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-ecm

I'm getting into sitecore Email Campaigns Manager (ECM).
I'm trying to create a newsletter.
So I go to E-mail campaigns -> Test Target Audience -> Drafts -> Newsletter Message and send messages (dispatch messages).
The audience recieves empty messages insted of beautiful HTML with images.
I also see white area instead of preview of a message.

Sitecore 6.3, ECM 1.1
I consider it's a bug. Have anyone came across this issue? What can be the reasons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Item "/sitecore/system/Modules/E-mail Campaign Manager" contains Renderer Url field. Have you set your website address in this field? This value is used for generating messages.
2. Have you published all items after installing the module?
3. When you open the Email Campaign Manager application for the first time, you are asked to set the Base URL. Have you set your website address there? This value is stored in the Base URL field of the "/sitecore/content/Home/E-mail Campaign" item.

Comment: Hi Ivan, I am working on Sitecore 6.5 and 6.4 ECM.When I create a new item under target audience(creating a new message),apart from HTML Message Template, 2 Columns, 1 Column and Newsletter templates are not displaying on the message preview. And when I dispatch them, apart from HTML Message, the other items using the other templates are sending blank message both subject and body. But it is ok for HTML Message. I already tried all 3 steps u mentioned. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: ECM 1.x has a predefined set of item templates that are considered as a message: `/sitecore/templates/Email Campaign/Messages/Plain Text Message`, `/sitecore/templates/Email Campaign/Messages/HTML Message`, `/sitecore/templates/Email Campaign/Messages/Pre-existing Page`. One-column, Two-column, Newsletter messages are based on the **Pre-existing Page** template. You can implement your own message design basing on the **Pre-existing Page** template. See item structure of these messages. They are implemented as branches (`/sitecore/templates/Branches/Email Campaign/Messages`).

Answer (score 1):

Have you been following the Installation steps?
Likely this is either due to that the information is not published, the base url isn't specified or the target audience can't find the url where the pictures are stored.

Answer (score 0):

Email previews will also fail if the webserver cannot browse to itself by DNS, because Sitecore makes a GET request to itself to fetch the email content.